# ReactJS MeteorJS Axios // 401 [Unauthorized] error

Tags: reactjs, meteor, get, axios

I am having some problems with fetching data from database written in Python. The code which I included to component is:

```js
axios.get('http://192.168.122:8000/messenger_api/fb_fanpages/', {
      headers: {
        'authorization': 'Token 539dec',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

And the error in the browser which I am recieving is

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uuwi.png)

I red plenty of articles and watched tutorials on youtube however I couldnt find the fix for my problem. I assume It is related to stack which I am using - maybe its becouse of Meteor? Another option which I am thinking of is, are headers - I used wrong syntax? however it is less possible, becouse as I said, I checked docs etc. end to me everything looks fine. I am not only sure about Meteor env or something. I also installed CORS extension for Chrome to exclude this option. Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: Little update. When I am using Insomia I can get the response.
I also added withCredentials: true to the code and now the error is 



XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 1):

How about you read the error message, it basically tells you the problem, which is a 401 (unauthorised).

In case you don't know, it means that the credentials you supplied were not accepted. I don't know if this code sample  has real credentials, I assume not.

Read the axios doco to make sure you are calling it right, and check the token to make sure it's a valid one

Comment: I did read it obviously, checked the credentials as well. Still doesnt work.

In mentioned docs there is nothing about passing two headers, so maybe I have to pass it different way.. dont know.

Another thing, there could be some problems with Meteor?

Thanks for participating

Comment: You could test it using Postman - it's probably quicker to try different things that way, and once you know you can get a response from the remote system, then yo do it with meteor/axios